Mother helps drug addict son suffering during withdrawal by giving him a fix
I only remember a scene from this movie:
A drug addict is locked up by his mother in a house to stop him from getting drugs. Seeing how much he suffers going through withdrawal the mother decides to give him a fix. She actually prepares the drugs in a spoon (using a lighter maybe). I remember they didn't have a syringe and had to improvise something. It was a pretty intense scene.
The movie probably appeared in the 90s or early 2000s and I don't think it was an american movie. I think they spoke Spanish or French, but I may be wrong.

I searched a lot but nothing helped but you can go through this list, may it helps http://www.imdb.com/list/qgYbmKCixGc/

@AnkitSharma Thank you for spending your time searching for an answer. It's hard to find something having so little information. I hope I'll get an answer from someone who has seen the movie and remembers this particular scene.

Bernardo Bertolucci's La Luna from 1979 has a similar scene: a mother tries to wean her son off heroin at home but can't bear to see him suffer and resorts to cooking a dose for him on a spoon over a candle. She doesn't have needles, however, so her son stabs his arm with a fork in desperation.

Seems like a good match to me, but could you please elaborate?

There are some great summaries of the film on Wiki and the movie database. I have trying to remember this movie, as well. This was very helpful.

I can flesh out the answer, if you want. I remember this scene. I guess I never came across this question before.

Added the details.

So it was italian after all.

Could it be the Spanish film Heroina? The trailer shows a mother just discovering her son using heroin in a public toilet. The movie came out in 2005. I cannot determine whether the mother locked her son up or helped him get drugs (my Spanish is pretty rudimentary and I haven't found a longer clip), but you may recognize the actors. The movie is based on a true story.


Could it be Trainspotting or Christiane F? 

Trainspotting is a weird and somewhat psychedelic movie with a young Ewan McGregor (Obi-Wan Kenobi from Star Wars) where his character decides to quit heroin. I only saw it half and many years ago unfortunately, so check Wikipedia for the plot.
Christiane F is a German movie about a 13-year old girl who gets addicted to heroin and shows the drug scenes and junkies of Berlin in the 70's or 80's. A really good movie and based on someone's real-life story by the way, I'd recommend it anyhow.
In this movie, the girl and her boyfriend (also addicted) go into rehab at her home. I'm not sure if they locked themselves up or if her mother did so, but her mother knows about it at that point.


Does not sound like Trainspotting. Renton is locked up by his parents, but they never prepare any drugs for him.
